# Filtering data from mysql using checkbox group

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys am making a website that lists multiple schools and activities that take place in each of them including sports and games. At one point, I want users to filter schools by selecting sports of their choice. Here's the html part:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="swimming"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="hockey"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="ping pong"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="rugby"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="soccer"/>
```

Here's the php

```
     if( isset($_POST['sport'])){

     $sport=implode(",",$_POST['sport']);

     $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schools WHERE sports LIKE '%$sport%'");
            while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
              //fetch a schools data

            }
      }
```

In the mysql db I have a column for sports and for each school, I have inserted the sports as follows:ping pong, tennis, soccer, rugby....and so on
I have discovered that if only one checkbox is selected, the code works perfect. But if more than one is selected, no results are found yet there are many schools that offer all of the above sports. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

First you will loop through all checkboxes ie having name sport then find with one is checked and then making a logic to concatenate and prepared a Like statement as Column LIKE '%keyword1%' OR Column LIKE 
'%keyword1%'

```
  $sport=" sports LIKE ";
 for($a=0;a<count($_POST['sport']);$a++){
if( isset($_POST['sport'][$a])){

         $sport.=($sport=="")?"":" OR sports LIKE";
         $sport.="'%".$_POST['sport'][$a]."%'"; 

    }



 }

   $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schools WHERE $sport ");
                while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                  //fetch a schools data
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, did that though the mysql final code after the checkboxes were selected was something like this "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE sports LIKE OR sports LIKE 'hockey' OR sports LIKE 'rugby' which resulted in an error so I made some changes. I added the percentage symbols to $sport.="'".$_POST['sport'][$a]."'"; so that now the code became $sport.="'%".$_POST['sport'][$a]."%'"; then I inserted a dummy value for $sport=" sports LIKE "; so that now the code was $sport=" sports LIKE '%,%'";

Comment: my pleasure, yes i missed the matching card(%) thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you're generating something like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE sports LIKE '%hockey,ping pong,soccer%'
```

which would only match records with that EXACT `hockey,ping pong,soccer` string in them.

What you want is more along the lines of:

```
SELECT ... WHERE sports IN ('hockey', 'ping pong', 'soccer')
```

e.g.

```
 $sports = "'" . implode("','",$_POST['sport']) . "'";
 $sql = "SELECT ... WHERE sports IN ($sports)";
```

And note that this is wide open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You should **NOT** use any of this code in a production system. It's simply to illustrate your problem and a potential (but still wrong) solution.

Comment: I tried that though it did not work. I think the mysql code SELECT ...WHERE sports IN ($sports) would work in a situation where the sports column only had one value like hockey alone rather than multiple values separated by commas like hockey, rugby, soccer

Comment: Then you should normalize your design. putting multiple distinct values into a single field is almost always a bad idea. Until you can revamp the structure/code, there's [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for this.